# Performant way to write lambda in std accumulate when init is string.

Tags: c++11, lambda, move-semantics

I was implementing some 
code that required something like this

```
const auto concat = std::accumulate(ints.begin(), ints.end(), string{}, 
[](string& acc, const int& val) { return string(std::move(acc))+to_string(val);});
```

2 questions:
1) is it safe to move from acc?
2) is it faster(than having `const string& acc` argument?

Comment: Even this should be safe, I believe: `[](string& acc, int val) -> string& { acc += to_string(val); return acc; }` No copies or moves at all (well, there's self-assignment, which may or may not be optimized). **[accumulate]/1** says that `std::accumulate` must update the accumulator by executing `acc = binary_op(acc, *i)`, and doesn't say that `binary_op` must not internally modify `acc` (which means that, yes, it should also be safe to move from `acc`).

Comment: @IgorTandetnik flagged for not-a-comment.  (joking, but why not answer?)

Comment: accepting comment :)